# Empty lines after check in of C# visual studio files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, encoding, escaping, perforce

I have checked the encoding (File --> Advanced Save Options --> Encoding) with my co-workers.

My File (on left) VS the same file on all other machines (on right)
[image]

Checked `line endings` and `encoding` settings on visual studio & every other options.

Though all are same, empty lines are inserted right after check-in. When I force take the same file from the Perforce server, still the file is displayed as on left but for all others it is displayed as on right side of the image.

EDIT: the file format is `utf8`, project is a `C#`, using `VS 2013` (not sure if this helps.)

Any ideas or pointers ?

Comment: There were several important bug fixes to the utf8 implementation in the server; I think one of them caused line-ending problems with older clients.. Check with Perforce Technical Support to verify that you have the latest patch level of your server.

Answer (score 0):

You say you check line endings on visual studio, did you also check the setting on the perforce workspace? (It auto-translates line endings and you can tell it which one you want on the client, which then also is what it expects to find after edits, to do the translation back to what is on the server.)